# How do I get VideoCapture to return errors instead of warnings?

Tags: python, opencv, error-handling, video-capture

When trying to implement a basic try/except statement to get frames from a camera on Linux I noticed that OpenCV does not raise an error when the camera is missing or the device index is wrong; instead it prints a warning. How could I catch this?

Example:

```
import cv2

def foo(camera_index):
    try:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index)
    except Exception:
        print("Couldn't open camera at {}".format(camera_index))
```

Running foo(1) with a working camera at /dev/video/0 will print:

`WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-kne9u3r2/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index`

My except is then useless because cv2 will never raise a proper exception (yet the message text sounds like an error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't catch those warnings, but you can check whether the `VideoCapture` object has been successfully created using [isOpened()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a9d2ca36789e7fcfe7a7be3b328038585) method.

As an example:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_index)
if not cap.isOpened():
  raise Exception("Couldn't open camera {}".format(camera_index))
```

Performing this check after creating a `VideoCapture` object is a common pattern; see [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#playing-video-from-file) for another example.

Comment: Excellent, this is just what I needed. Thanks :)